# iOS Native Project Integrates Vuforia Unity Project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have two projects. One is native iOS app (UIKIT) and the other is AR Vuforia project which was made by Unity3D.

I can export AR project into XCODE project, but I am wondering how to link them together.

For example, I have a button on native iOS app. I want to trigger AR project when button is pressed and it can go back to native iOS app as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally worked it out by myself. Unity project must be rootviewcontroller, but you could add a separate navigation controller on the top of unity. You could add native code into AppController.m

Communication between native and unity is quiet simple.

Call

> UnitySendMessage (gameObj, methodName, msg);

to send message to unity method

Use

> extern "C"

to receive call back from unity.

I can provide some sample code if someone needs it.

Comment: Hi Jinwei ! I aslo work hard on IOS8 Argument Reality with Vuforia. So far  I tried using Vuforia 4.0 + SceneKit and tried opening Unity + Vuforia 4.0 game view in native app (ref : http://www.the-nerd.be/2014/08/06/add-unity3d-in-a-native-ios-application/ ), but both failed with something problem... So can you provied some sample code with me? Thanks very much !!

Comment: Would love to see some sample code or some more explanation for this.